# Outlook email sending specific internal user to spambox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010

I work at an IT Company and one of our clients has an Exchange Server 2010 on-site hosting their email.

So with this user, lets call him Bob, receives email from Josh. When Bob receives an email from Josh, it goes straight to Spam no matter what.

- I have reviewed the configuration of the Exchange server to make sure
  that Josh is not in a blacklist of any sort.
- On Bob's Outlook profile i have made sure Josh is in the Safe Senders
  list as well as created a NEW Outlook profile just to make sure his
  profile didn't get messed up in any way.
- I have also removed any other Antivirus that is not provided by us
  just in case it had an email filter of some sort.
- I made a rule on his outlook to move Josh's emails to his Inbox and
  ran the rule on the entire email. Seconds later all his emails from
  Josh were moved right back into spam.
- I even logged into the WebApp of Outlook and checked to see if there
  were any synced rules from other devices but the only rule on there
  was the one i added myself.
- i have run Outlook in safemode to disable any addons it may have but
  none of these changes are fixing the issue.

Completely out of ideas, does anyone have any idea why just Josh is being sent as spam?

Thanks

Comment: Is josh external? Do any other emails from the same domain as josh get delivered correctly? If you moved all the mail to the inbox and seconds later it moved back to spam, I think you eliminate many many things. I’m pretty sure both exchange and outlook classify the email when it arrives. It will not move it afterwards. You can also eliminate the entire mail path of arrival. It sounds to me this user has something on some connected device moving this email to spam. Is there a phone or anything connected to the account? You need to identify all connected devices and eliminate them one by one.

Comment: Both Bob and Josh are internal within the same domain. Bob does have a phone connected to his email but he rarely uses it. Guess I'll have to tackle that next...

Comment: @Appleoddity Totally old but if you post your comment as answer, this resolved my issue, it was his phone all along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that this is caused by the users Samsung mobiles spam filter, it creates the Spambox folder repeatedly, turn it off and it will go away ;)

Comment: are you sure about this?

Comment: This solved it for me!  Both answers are correct, but it was a samsung phone in my case. We found that the client had accidently added users to the 'spam addresses' setting and a new folder called 'spambox' was made and moving legit emails into it.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Appleoddity](https://superuser.com/users/750903/appleoddity) in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1292349/outlook-email-sending-specific-internal-user-to-spambox#comment1914119_1292349):

> Is josh external? Do any other emails from the same domain as josh get delivered correctly? If you moved all the mail to the inbox and seconds later it moved back to spam, I think you eliminate many many things. I’m pretty sure both exchange and outlook classify the email when it arrives. It will not move it afterwards. You can also eliminate the entire mail path of arrival. It sounds to me this user has something on some connected device moving this email to spam. Is there a phone or anything connected to the account? You need to identify all connected devices and eliminate them one by one.

The OP [xR34P3Rx](https://superuser.com/users/401554/xr34p3rx) responded with [the following comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1292349/outlook-email-sending-specific-internal-user-to-spambox#comment1914125_1292349):

> Turns out, even though Bob and Josh are internal within the same domain, Bob has a phone connected to his email, although he rarely uses it. It was his phone all along.

Answer (score 0):

One of my Exchange users reported the same issue today - when he receives an email from another Exchange user, the email stays 1 or 2 seconds in the Inbox, then it disappears.

After checking his Outlook, I found the email is parked in a folder called **Spambox**, and, on his mobile device, I found a few email addresses in the email app's "Spam Email Address" list that were routing those emails to **Spambox**.  The issue was resolved by deleting those addresses from the email app.